# Python pause excution whenever a condition is met and resume where it left if condition is unmet again

Tags: python, memory-management, while-loop

I have a memory greedy script and I dont want to freeze my computer while running it.
I need to pause excution whenever the memory usage exceeds a limit lets say 60% and then get back where it left. I think this is not a very programming practice.

lets say I have a code:

```
while True:
      do this stuff
      and this other stuff
      and this other ...
      ...
```

The only solution I know is to plague the code with many:

```
while psutil.virtual_memory().percent >memory_limit:
      time.sleep(30)
```

between lines, like this:

```
while True:
      while psutil.virtual_memory().percent >memory_limit:
              time.sleep(30)
      do this stuff
      while psutil.virtual_memory().percent >memory_limit:
              time.sleep(30) 
      and this other stuff
      while psutil.virtual_memory().percent >memory_limit:
              time.sleep(30) 
      and this other ...
      while psutil.virtual_memory().percent >memory_limit:
              time.sleep(30) 
      ...
```

what is not a nice code, the most aproximate solution to that would be

```
while not psutil.virtual_memory().percent >memory_limit:
      do this stuff
      and this other stuff
      and this other ...
      ...
else:
     time.sleep(30)
```

but this restarts the excution instead of resuming.

Why python doesn't have an integrated whenever to do this.

Answer (score 0):

More information is needed.

Usually the only thing that will consume loads of memory is either a memory leak, or large data sets.  Memory leaks can be fixed and large data sets can be handled in different ways to reduce the amount of memory being used. Pausing the program is not going to reduce how much memory it is consuming.

If you can provide the actual code being used it would be extremely helpful in order to come up with the best solution.

---EDIT---

You probably have some kind of loop that goes over the data you are reading. I do not know what size chunks of data you are dealing with and what the actual data is being read from (local file, network data....) so that makes it harder to give the proper solution.

Here are some examples of things you can do. You will have to alter them in order to use them in your code.

```
    import threading
import psutil

memory_event = threading.Event()

MEMORY_LIMIT = 60.0


def check_memory():
    memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
    percent = ((memory.total - memory.available) / memory.total) * 100.0

    while percent > MEMORY_LIMIT:
        memory_event.wait(10)
        memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
        percent = ((memory.total - memory.available) / memory.total) * 100.0


data = open('some_path_to_data', 'r')

while data:
    check_memory()
    
    # no need to call check memory multiple times because the data that 
    # is loaded  only gets pulled into memory when readline  gets called
    line = data.readline()
```

Another option is to use threads. This is a more complex way to go about it but it is probably a better way as it will be able to check the memory  use every 100 milliseconds

```
import threading
import psutil


memory_event = threading.Event()
exit_event = threading.Event()
main_thread_stall = threading.Event()

MEMORY_LIMIT = 60.0


def check_memory_thread():
    while not exit_event.is_set():
        memory = psutil.virtual_memory()
        percent = ((memory.total - memory.available) / memory.total) * 100.0
        if percent > MEMORY_LIMIT:
            memory_event.clear()
        else:
            memory_event.set()

        # a 0.1 second wait doesn't cause excessive cpu usage
        exit_event.wait(0.1)


def data_parser_thread():
    # wait until there is enough memory available
    memory_event.wait()
    
    while not exit_event.is_set():
        with open('some_path_to_data', 'r') as f:
            data = f.read()

        # do work on data

        # finished parsing data so exit the program
        if data == '':
            exit_event.set()
            break

        # wait until there is enough memory available
        memory_event.wait()

    try:
        # join the memory thread to make sure it exits properly
        memory_thread.join()
    except threading.ThreadError:
        pass

    # stops the main thread from waiting.
    main_thread_stall.set()


memory_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_memory_thread)
data_thread = threading.Thread(target=check_memory_thread)

memory_thread.start()
data_thread.start()


try:
    main_thread_stall.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    exit_event.set()
    try:
        # join the memory thread to make sure it exits properly
        memory_thread.join()
    except threading.ThreadError:
        pass

    memory_event.clear()


# make sure the data thread has exited before terminating the program
try:
    # join the data thread to make sure it exits properly
    data_thread.join()
except threading.ThreadError:
    pass
```

NOTE: Both of the code examples are pseudo code and have not been tested. They are for example only and they will have to be modified and tested for your specific application. Without seeing the actual code you are using I am not going to be able to provide a specific way to solve your problem.

Comment: option 2 large datasets. Sure it is not but let-s say there's another program consuming memory like firefox or whatever stuff on the system, this would instruct the program until some memory is free and if that's not enough yeah termination is the only solution.

Comment: So it's not the script that is consuming the memory it's other programs? The best way would be to get more ram or to increase the amount of paging space that is allocated in the OS.  I will edit my answer to provide a couple of examples if you do not want to do the above suggestions.

Comment: The program has large datasets and in top of that i'm using firefox, I could intruct the pebcak to stop doing that but i don't know the function, anyway I'm doing things on the fly and there's much to improove, I'm using python2emotion to compare texts when a similarity checking would work as well. But python2emotion can work over a promedium of the dataset, while for comparing texts I have to write a new function and test it. I'm doing a predictive model of languaqge btw, and now trying some evolution improovement with python2emotion but all of this in the simplest way.

Comment: I edited my post to provide a couple of ways that may help.

Comment: I did also want to mention  that "percent" is not available for psutil.virtual_memory() and is only available for psutil.swap_memory()

Comment: I'm sorry I must correct you, In my case it worked with no error, have you tested that? May be it's not in the spacs but it works.

Comment: I was reading the documentation to psutil and they show percent  being available for swap_memory and it doesn't show it for virtual_memory. https://psutil.readthedocs.io/en/latest/#psutil.virtual_memory

Comment: Just try it, I did it because I haven't read the documention and one of the strings in the psutil.virtual_memory() list is exactly 'percent=x' with x a number, so why not try if it has a fuction with that name. For the ignorant, ingenuity is an advantage.

Answer (score 0):

You could use multi-threading. Have a function with a while loop (add a sleep(1) or something in there so it doesn't run too much) and then just put that on a separate thread to the main program.

Threading basics: https://realpython.com/intro-to-python-threading/

It could look like this:

```
def do_stuff():
  do_stuff

def check():
    check
threads = []
t = threading.Thread(target=check())
t.daemon = True
threads.append(t)
#You could do the same for the other function (I wont include that as it is just the same thing)

for thread in threads:
    thread.start()

for thread in threads:
    thread.join()
```

Comment: you introduce me to the right path, though you see the flaws in programming whenever you have to import multiprocessing module when just an integrated while (different to the actual one) could do it, or lets call it whenever whenever stuff: stuff, else: another stuff. In this cases I really miss batch and it's spagetti code.